# Using topomerge to create states from school districts

Tags: d3.js, geojson, topojson

I've created a [continental US school district topojson file](https://github.com/CenterForAssessment/SGPspatialData/blob/master/Shape_Files/Topojson_2016/USA_Districts_ID.topojson) and am attempting to use topomerge to create state shapes from the district topojson file using the following CLI command:

```
topomerge states=districts -k 'd.id' < USA_Districts_ID.topojson > USA_States.topojson
```

This leads to the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

I've followed suggestions from [here](https://github.com/topojson/topojson-client/blob/master/README.md) and [here](https://github.com/topojson/topojson/pull/147#issuecomment-38989103) but still can't resolve the issue.

Any ideas greatly appreciated!